# Find Element in xml that inserted by an user input

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

Hi I am a beginner in Python

i want retrive data within an element and the ID of the element defined by the user
please see my attempt below

thanks for your help

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sa.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

segment_id=input()
print(segment_id)
#for y in root[21].findall(".//*[@ID='PG4022R']"):
for y in root[21].find('.//div[@ID="segment_id"]//input'):
```

the idea is- the user will insert'PG4022R' as "segment_id"
and that value then to use by the code to find data

the reason is i have another bit of code where i will need that'PG4022R' to find more data

```
for x in root[21].findall(".//*[@ID='segment_id']/Segment-Berth-Route-List"):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using f-strings to insert the variable:

```
for y in root[21].find(f'.//div[@ID="{segment_id}"]//input')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, tried it did not work, return with the following

for y in root[21].find(f'.//div[@ID="{segment_id}"]//input'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

Before executing Please refer this xml doc: [XML Reference for this Code](https://pastebin.com/index/tsQgjXGP)

Here is my Updated Code : (Just Try with This)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xmlfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
l1 = []
a = input('Enter Tag Name : ')
print('The below are the corresponding id of the tag '+a)
for x in root.findall(a):
    item =x.attrib.get('id')
    l1.append(item)
print(l1)
c = input('Enter the ids with , seperated (min 2 ) : ')
d = c.split(',')
print(d)
for y in root.findall(a):
    for z in y:
        if y.attrib.get('id') in d:
            print(z.text)
```

Output :

```
Enter Tag Name : book
The below are the corresponding id of the tag book
['bk101', 'bk103', 'bk104', 'bk105', 'bk106', 'bk107', 'bk108', 'bk109', 'bk110', 'bk111', 'bk112']
Enter the ids with , seperated (min 2 ) : bk101,bk103,bk104
['bk101', 'bk103', 'bk104']
Gambardella, Matthew
XML Developer's Guide
Computer
44.95
2000-10-01
An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.
Corets, Eva
Maeve Ascendant
Fantasy
5.95
2000-11-17
After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.
Corets, Eva
Oberon's Legacy
Fantasy
5.95
2001-03-10
In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.
```

Here is my OLD code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xmlfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
a = input('Enter Tag Name : ')
for x in root.findall(a):
    item =x.attrib.get('id')
    print(item)
    for y in x:
        print(y.text)
```

Output :

```
Enter Tag Name : rock
bk102
Ralls, Kim
Midnight Rain
Fantasy
5.95
2000-12-16
A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.
```

This above code will print the id attribute value and the entire data of the tag name which you give through input.(in doc the second child has rock tag you can refer the document)

Optional Code But important in handling tag attributes and child tag data:

This Code which prints the all attributes of the entered tag name

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xmlfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
a = input('Enter Tag Name : ')
for x in root.findall(a):
    item =x.attrib
    print(item)
```

Output :

```
Enter Tag Name : rock
{'id': 'bk102'}
```

This code will print selected attribute of the tag name given as User Input

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xmlfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
a = input(''Enter Tag Name')
for x in root.findall(a):
    item =x.attrib.get('id')
    print(item)
```

Output :

```
Enter Tag Name : rock
bk102
```

This code will handle the individual children whatever the child you want. In my case I just accessed only author and description of the rock tag.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xmlfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
a = input('Enter Tag Name : ')
for x in root.findall(a):
    author =x.find('author').text
    description = x.find('description').text
    print('author = ',author)
    print('description = ',description)
```

Output :

```
Enter Tag Name : rock
author =  Ralls, Kim
description =  A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, for the response

I had looked in your xml what if you need access to a spec id in a book for example: book id="bk104"
when i enter the tag 'book' it return with all of the data with for all of the book tag.
What would be command for retrieving a specific ID ( for example bk1040 )with in the book tag?
Also what would be the command if i want to retrieve data of multiple id by one command for example - bk103, bk105, bk108 by one command rather entering one by one?
thanks

Comment: Hi Tanvir I just Updated the answer with my new Code you can try with that.

Comment: Hi Saragada,
Thank you very much it helped.
I still have a question
How to retrieve data for multiple id 
In the 
    b = input('Enter the id : ')
I want to enter bk105+ bk106+ bk108 at the same time and get the data

Comment: Like you want to enter all the id's which are present in the list at a time? If yes for which Id you want to retrieve data?(example in list there are three values bk101,bk103,bk104, if you enter three values at time you want all three id's data or in that also selected data) Please elaborate your question

Comment: SR:Like you want to enter all the id's which are present in the list at a time?
 TH: yes
SR: If yes for which Id you want to retrieve data?(example in list there are three values bk101,bk103,bk104…
TH: data for all three ids. After entering bk101,bk103,bk104 I want it return data for all 3 like below. 
Enter the id : bk101
Gambardella, Matthew
XML Developer's Guide
Computer
44.95
2000-10-01
An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.
Enter the id : bk103
Corets, Eva
Maeve Ascendant
Fantasy
5.95
2000-11-17
After the collapse of a nanotechnology ..

Comment: Hi Tanvir i just updated the code you can try with it.

Comment: Hi Saragada, thank you for the update. Really appreciate your spirit to help.

Comment: Hi Saragada, thank you for the update. Really appreciate your spirit to help.  It is not quite i was looking for. it does not work if i enter bk101,bk103,bk104 in one chunk. still needs enter one by one. in my test code keep on requesting for an ID does not know when to stop. Do you think it will if we try to store our requested Id bk101,bk103,bk104 (may be as a list) and then modify the code such  that it retrieves data for all of the 'id's from that stored list?

Comment: Hi Tanvir please look into the updated code. I have changed it.Please try with that